# How to get text from div style using JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup

how to get the text "xxxx" and it's url using JSOUP.

```html
<div style="width:45%;float:left;border: dashed 1px #966;margin:0 10px;padding:10px;height:400px;">
    <ul>  
        <li><a href="http://xxx.xxx.com/Title?xxxxx" target="_blank">xxxx</a></li>
        <li><b>years：</b>2015</li>
        <li><b>language：</b>non </li>
        <li><b>color：</b>color</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my current approach but I receive nothing:

```
Elements mvYearElement = doc.select("div[style*=width:45%;float:left;border: dashed.1px #966;margin:0 10px;padding:10px;height:400px;]");
```

Comment: Are there more href links in the document that you want to avoid or why do you specify the style tag of the div explicitly?

Comment: Above of html is just a part of a page and more href links in page. Specifying the style tag is a reason that is unique in this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that styles do not need to appear in an particular order. Your selector however fixates the order and lists a lot of styles. I would try to identify the part of the style the really is discriminating the link and only use this part. Since I don't know the rest of the HTML i only could guess what is that discriminating part. This maybe?

```
Elements els = doc.select(div[style*=dashed]);
```

That is only a wild guess however. But maybe it is also the contents of the div that are discriminating it from the others? In that case you could do something like this:

```
Elements els = doc.select(div[style]:has(ul));
```

Or something else. If you would share more of the HTML I could be more specific.